# Isometries preserving distance but not angles

Tags: geometry, inner-products, isometry

In Euclidean geometry, every distance-preserving map (isometry) also preserves angles between two vectors.

Is there any example of a non-Euclidean geometry in which an isometry need not preserve the angle between two vectors?

Answer (score 6):

No. In any Riemmanian geometry, the angle $\theta \in [0, \pi]$ between two nonzero vectors ${\bf a}, {\bf b}$ satisfies
$$\cos \theta = \frac{{\bf a} \cdot {\bf b}}{||{\bf a}|| \, ||{\bf b}||};$$ any isometry preserves the r.h.s. and hence the angle.

Conversely, there *are* maps that preserve angles by are not isometries, for example, any scaling of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I know that $\theta$ is defined as you have given in the standard Euclidean geometry; can you give me a reference for this in Riemannian geometry?

Comment: I don't have it offhand, but probably this is in Lee's *Riemannian Geometry*, as well as any sufficiently thorough discussion of conformal geometry.

Comment: OK! I will see it. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: You're welcome, I hope it was useful. Note that this is really the only sensible definition, as for any point $x$ on a Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$, the inner product space $(T_x M, g_x)$ is isomorphic to Euclidean space with the standard inner product, and via this identification the above definition of angle is exactly the usual Euclidean definition of angle.

Answer (score 0):

In Riemannian geometry, once you have a surjective distance preserving continuous map (note, no assumptions on differentiability) then you are automatically a smooth isometry (i.e. preserve inner products of tangent vectors). This is one of Myers-Steenrood theorems. Conversely, every isometry clearly preserves distances.